# What are the extra arguments in InvokePerform() AMPScript function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api

There are no examples on the usage of the [**InvokePerform()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/invokeperform.htm) AMPScript function in the official documentation -- at least that I can find.

Doing some testing and comparing the usage to the [**SOAP API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api.htm), I noticed there are three more valid arguments.  Here's my code to start a `QueryDefinition`:

```
%%[

var @rr, @objectID, @queryDefinitions
set @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "QueryDefinition")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "ObjectID")

set @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "CustomerKey")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", "DataExtensionTest")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter", @sfp)

set @queryDefinitions = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @rrStatus, @rrRequestID)

if rowcount(@queryDefinitions) > 0 then

  var @queryDefinition, @ObjectID, @obj

  set @queryDefinition = Row(@queryDefinitions, 1)
  set @ObjectID = Field(@queryDefinition, "ObjectID")

  set @obj = CreateObject("QueryDefinition")

  SetObjectProperty(@obj, "ObjectID", @ObjectID )
  Set @performStatusCode = InvokePerform(@obj, "start", @performStatusMessage, @unknown1, @unknown2, @performResult)

endif

]%%
queryDefinitions: %%=rowcount(@queryDefinitions)=%%
<br>performStatusCode: %%=v(@performStatusCode)=%%
<br>performStatusMessage: %%=v(@performStatusMessage)=%%
<br>unknown1: %%=v(@unknown1)=%%
<br>unknown2: %%=v(@unknown2)=%%
<br>performResult: %%=v(@performResult)=%%
```

**Output**

```
queryDefinitions: 1 
performStatusCode: OK 
performStatusMessage: QueryDefinition perform called successfully 
unknown1: 0 
unknown2: 
performResult: ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.PerformResult
```

Anyone know what `@unknown1` and `@unknown2` represent?

I also can't figure out for the life of me how to retrieve the values returned in the `PerformResult`.  If anyone has some insight on that, I'd love to know.

Comment: From an initial look unknown1 could be an error code, 0 meaning OK in API terms. unknown2 could be last error code which has references in the Core library. I'll do some more digging and report back.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit more information found in the [AMPscript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/invokeperform/)

Comment: LOL.  I'm the co-author of The AMPscript Guide.  I asked this question for the book!

Comment: That's pretty amazing, and now I feel I have deserved this. Feel free to downvote me. :)